# Insert attribute in table if it is not null using Hibernate

Tags: java, database, spring, hibernate, annotations

I have mapping class defined as:

```
@Table(name = "TEST_TABLE")
public class DBTestAccount
{
    @Id
    @Column(name = "UUID", nullable = false, length = 36)
    private String uuid;

    @Column(name = "REGION")
    private String region;

    @Column(name = "COUNTRY")
    private String countryCode;

    //getters and setters
}
```

Now I need to update the table. For that let's say I create following object:

```
DBTestAccount dbTestAccount = new DBTestAccount();
dbTestAccount.setUuid("testUUID");
dbTestAccount.setRegion("testRegion");
dbTestAccount.setCountryCode(null);
```

Now let's say initially in the table we have a record that has some value of `COUNTRY`. Inserting the above object will replace the value and make `COUNTRY` null. I want that it should update the data, but if the column is null, then it should ignore and do not update it. If it is non-null then it should update it. How to achieve this in hibernate? Is there an annotation to do so? If not then what is the possible solution (except using `if - else`). Can I create a custom annotation for this?

PS:
The underlying database is PostgreSQL.

Comment: Are you sure you are presenting the full picture? E.g.: If your country code column is not nullable then you should experience an SQL exception and never ever will be able overwriting the row.

Comment: @rpy This is the full picture. Country can be nullable. But once it is assigned a non-null value, then it should be never be assigned null.

Comment: What is preventing you from coding that behavior into the setter for the countryCode field of DBTestAccount?

Comment: Right. But I wanted a generic thing.

Comment: This is not  a generally valid problem. Usually your application is in charge of managing data. It then either will never insert nulls or if the value is not known at time of first insert will later read the value and explicitly use a setter on the missing value. In such case you will already have special code. So, your use case is highy specific and you may not expect general support for such.

Comment: @rpy We have a similar annotation when we insert in DynamoDB.

Answer (score 0):

The example you are describing can't be present in the database, because the object is not an entity yet, as it is created with new keyword and it isn't yet persisted in the database.

From your explanation, what I got, is that you want to save only changed attributes. For that purpose hibernate has the [Dynamic Update](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.1/javadocs/org/hibernate/annotations/DynamicUpdate.html) annotation.

Comment: But initially my country code was not null, now it is null. Even with that annotation, it will update. That is what I don't want.